# What does "pending edit" mean in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, edits, first-questions

I recently got enough privilege/reputation to review posts. Considering all the help I got from SO, I am honored for such a role, and I have been motivated at first in doing reviews.

But I got stuck in the same "full edit queue"-related issue already discussed a lot here. And I have not reviewed all 80 questions as recommended.

Today, I see this alternative "pending edit", alongside "Looks OK" and "Share feedback". It's for one of the questions in the First questions review queue.

When choosing "pending edit", nothing happens. What exactly does this alternative mean? Why does nothing happen when we choose it and hit "Submit"? I think that it must have something to do with someone has already edited that question. Maybe it's also because the edit queue is full (as always).

What should we do in this case? Skip it? Set as "Looks OK"?

Comment: You need 2k reputation points to review suggested edits: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit ("*In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing suggested edits (which previously you would have had to suggest). These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit.*")

Comment: Hi @cgien and Gino, I got what you mean: "pending edit" means someone had already edited the post, and just one edit for each post is possible. It can be ok after that, or not, make suggestions unrelated to editing if any, or, in doubt, skip... Ok, thank you. It was the first time I saw it and I thought it was a bug because nothing happened...